# Export helper functions with Material-UI theme support

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, localization, material-design, tsx

I want to create a new file that will contain helper functions for several components that using the same logic,
The issue is that I need to use my `locale.ts` file in that file for using the current language according to the theme (localization)
but it seems I can't call `const t: any = useTheme().props` in ts file.
(error: React Hook "useTheme" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function)

today in my tsx component files:

```
t: any = useTheme().props
t.General.someString
```

How can I use localization of the Material-UI theme in my helper functions file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook cannot be used at the top level, this is unsupported:

```
// top level
const any = useTheme().props;
```

It's supposed to be used inside a functional component or another hook. For reference, see the rules of hook [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions):

```
function Component() {
  // valid because it's inside a React function
  const any = useTheme().props;
  return (...);
}
```

What you can do is create a helper hook that returns a specific data that you need:

```
const useThemeProps = () => {
  // valid because it's inside another hook
  return useTheme().props;
}
```

```
function Component() {
  const any = useThemeProps();
  return (...);
}
```

You can also just return the data directly:

```
function Component() {
  const { props } = useTheme();
  return (...);
}
```

Comment: How will the helper hook help me? it's still a hook and i can't use it int top level file

Comment: @Ar26 if you need to access the theme object outside of the functional component, create a default theme using [`createTheme()`](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#theme-provider) and pass it to the `ThemeProvider`.

Comment: Actually, I used your idea - created a helper hook in the top-level file and call the useTheme().props inside the hook, using it to build my localized objects and call this hook in my functional component, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me

Inside Utils.js file

```
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';

const IsMobile = () => {
  return useMediaQuery(useTheme().breakpoints.down('md'));
};

export { IsMobile };
```

Inside component:

```
import { IsMobile } from 'components/utilities/Utils';
```

Test

```
console.log(IsMobile());
```

In JSX

```
{IsMobile ? () : ()}
```